# the ID is not being sent from 1 page to another via form submit

Tags: php

I am trying to send the username from 1 page to the next at the click of a form the image details is being sent but the username isnt.

```
<?php

    // Connect to server and select database.
    include("connect.php");

    //Get username from address bar
    $username=$_GET['id'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM image_upload WHERE user = '$username'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //test is username is being sent to this page
    echo "select image to $username folder";
?>

<form action="process.php?id=<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here is what the code is for the process.php page incase this is where the problem is.

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$username=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM image_upload WHERE user = '$username'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
    $tmp_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

    //Get current working directory
    $curdir = getcwd();

    //testing uploaded file is an image
    if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
    {
         //testing out information has passed over
         echo "$username";
         echo "<br>";
         echo "$curdir now has $imageType";
         echo "<br>";
         echo "$imageName";
         echo "<br>";
    }else{
         echo "Sorry images only";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Besides the fact that your code is obsolete and wide open to attack, you don't check for errors. How do you expect to know what's wrong if you don't look?

Comment: where it should display the name on the next page its just blank

Comment: You need to check the `$_GET` array. The username is there if your query returned results.

Comment: on the address bar on the process page its showing http://localhost/process.php?id=

Comment: You're query is not running and returning a result. You're not doing any error checking, so you don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    // Connect to server and select database.
    include("connect.php");

    //Get username from address bar
    $username=$_GET['id'];

    //Validate and Sanitize the username

    $sql="SELECT * FROM image_upload WHERE user = '$username'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    /*
      you already have the username from $_GET[]
      but if you want it from image_upload
      you need to use the correct column name to start.

      Look at your query WHERE user = '$username'";
      "user" is the column name, so......
    */
    $userid = $row['user'];

    //test is username is being sent to this page
    echo "select image to $username folder";

    // Personally I'd pass the username in the form as a hidden input
?>

<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" />
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Updated version...**

```
<?php

    //Get username from address bar -- sanitize it
    $username = strip_tags(trim($_GET['id'])); 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    include("connect.php");
    $n = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM image_upload WHERE user = '$username'"),0);
    IF ($n) {

        $response = '
<form action="process.php" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$username.'">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>';

    }ELSE{

        $response = "<p>No match for ".$username."</p>";

    }
    mysql_close($connection); // change this to match your $conn var

    echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: tried that and still nothing on process page for username

Comment: Are you using $_Post['id'] to retrieve the id? Also, there needs to be a row in the table with that username to return a result. Make sure there is a result and the column names are correct.

Comment: the field in mysql is user

Comment: Try the updated version. If the form loads then there is an issue on the process.php page. If it shows "no match" error message, then the problem is with the table/columns.

Comment: it displays the upload form but when i run it, it displays $username instead of the actual name

Comment: change value in the form to value="'.$username.'"> ... updated the code above. typo, sorry.

Comment: that worked thank you very much - and thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put values in the `action` attribute when using POST unless you want them stripped off by the browser. Even when using GET, its bad practice to put values in the `action`. Put them in a `<input type='hidden' />`

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" />
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with query strings in a POST action. There's nothing in the HTTP spec that expressely forbids it.

Comment: most of what i am doing is what ive learned from tutorial websites as im home learning it - done a college course about 5 years ago.

Comment: @DerekKennedy you will also have to use `$_POST['id']` to retrieve the value after making this change (rather than `$_GET['id']`).